# How to use wildcard in gsub replacement

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have a column of strings, e.g.

```
strings <- c("SometextPO0001moretext", "SometextPO0008moretext")
```

The 'sometext' and 'moretext' portions are variable in length.  I want to remove the PO000* portion of the strings, where * is a wildcard.  I've tried

```
gsub("PO000*", "", strings)
```

and Googled quite a bit but surprisingly haven't found an answer to this seemingly simple question.  Since the last character varies, I  would like to be able to do the removal this way vs. hard-coding a large number of variants.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single wild card, you need to use a `.`. `*` which you have used is repeate 0 or more times for the last character, which was `0`.

`gsub("PO000.", "", strings)` would remove both `PO0001` and `PO0008`

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `gsub("PO000\\d{1}", "", strings)`
And the result is :

```
[1] "Sometextmoretext" "Sometextmoretext"
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer also works.  Awarded the first one because it is simpler

Comment: @kng229 Fine, his answer is more detail, I just post what I thought.